# Exporting Custom Image from OCI to Another Cloud Provider

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am needing assistance in exporting a custom ubuntu image made in OCI, to another cloud provider such as AWS, GCP, Orange, etc.  Is there any way to do this?  Please be detailed, as I have not found a process to successfully execute this.

Tried exporting into a bucket, and pulling from there, but was not successful.

- Origin: OCI
- Destination: AWS, GCP, Orange
- OS: Ubuntu